# Why does FireFtp disconnect automatically after 120 seconds?

Tags: firefox, ftp, fireftp

I'm creating a website and uploading files onto that website with FireFtp. When I don't do anything on FireFtp for 120 seconds and then try to do something, I get the following error message:

> 421 Timeout (no operation for 120 seconds)

FireFtp disconnects from my account automatically after 120 seconds and I have to log in again. After a while, this gets quite annoying.

Why is this? Is there a way to keep it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open FireFTP URL and press `Shift+Alt+T` (Alternatively click on `Tools` in its menu bar).
2. Go to `Options`.
3. Then to `Connections`.
4. Below `Connection Recovery` you can set `Network Timeout` option to a value between `1` and `600`. Your current value must be `120`.

Also check if your `Keep alive connection while idle` option is checked.

Comment: My current value of Network timeout is 30 and the Keep alive connection while idle is checked. I tried to change the value of Network timeout from 30 to 600, but after 120 seconds, it still gives the error message "421 Timeout (no operation for 120 seconds)".

Comment: Then I guess it is a limitation imposed by the server. Do you have access to the FTP server configuration files?

Comment: Tecnically with these changes your configuration is correct. I am afraid that the limitation depends upon the FTP server.